# Is there a reason to use Copy Column over Derived Column in SSIS?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Is there a reason to use Copy Column over Derived Column? They both seem to do the same task when you try to copy a column?

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of just creating a copy of a column they both can get you to you end result with no major differences in performance.

One major benefit to using a derived column over a copy column is the fact that derived column task allows for the use of error output where copy column has no such feature.